CSS height issue
Всем привет, нужна подсказка по css и html. У меня есть текстовое поле , которое должно менять свою высоту по мере заполнения, то есть если написано 2 строки в длину, то высота поля должна быть эквивалентна высоте двух строк, я пробовал использовать auto для height в css, но оно для нуля или одной строки, ставит уже сразу высоту в 2 строки, помогите решить, может можно через скрипт как-то написать?

Вот, введён 1 символ, то есть по факту используется одна строка, но он ставит высоту как для двух.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202
